# Is there a solana cli for the terminal like eth-cli?

Tags: cli

I have a solana private key and I want to make a send transaction and check balances with it. Is there a Solana cli command that can do this? eth-cli works well with ethereum since I can pass in the private key of and eth address to make a transaction. Is there a solana cli like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solana CLI is the [Solana Tool Suite](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools).

The CLI has a number of tools such as keypair generation, staking, and more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, see [here](https://docs.solana.com/cli/conventions).

I like it very much, it's awesome.